# Documentation for Shopware 6 Admin API. What are possible commands?

Tags: api, rest, shopware

I got the task to integrate the systems of our old shop to Shopware 6. So I have to deal with the Admin API. The documentation says:

> The Admin API is designed in such a way that all entities of the
> system can be read in the same way. Once an entity is registered in
> the system, it can be written and read via API

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/admin-api/reading-entities

How do those entities work? Is there a list/documentation of all default entities? Do I have to register the entities myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Shopware 6 API documentation sources

There is a public Shopware 6 API documentation (admin API and store API) available at

- For Shopware >= 6.4: https://shopware.stoplight.io/
- All versions: https://swagger.docs.fos.gg/

##### Local Documentation

Otherwise you can use the `/api/v{version}/_info/swagger.html` as pointed out by Valerii.

Be advised that **starting from Shopware 6.4**, the **API version is no longer used** in requests. So [as per documentation](http://%20https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/integrations-api/general-concepts/api-versioning#how-do-i-actually-open-up-the-swagger-page) you have to open something like

`https://your-shop-url.invalid/api/_info/swagger.html`

Make sure you have set

```
APP_ENV=dev
```

in your `.env` and use this only locally and not on a publicly accessible server.

The advantage of using the local documentation is, that you will also see endpoints which are introduced by additional extensions.

### Reverse engineering instead of documentation

In addition you can always check the network tab of your browser when doing the intented action in the Shopware admin panel, and learn about the necessary requests.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to register "default" entities that are provided by Shopware core. But if you define your own custom entity you have to register it as a service. You can get a list of entities that are registered in the core using /api/v{version}/_info/swagger.html endpoint which generates swagger UI docs.

Comment: Unfortunally the swagger fails because it cannot load
https://cdn.shopware.store/assets/v/21a15245/bundles/framework/swagger-ui-bundle.js
and 
https://cdn.shopware.store/assets/v/21a15245/bundles/framework/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js
 – – –
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>
assets/v/21a15245/bundles/framework/swagger-ui-bundle.js
</Key>
<RequestId>DZM0EYMJTTVSWBKS</RequestId>
<HostId>
bF0T183/yD2bKSNOC4Z+bRbkwAIhLUCjB38Ips255en7RJNKKIGOEE3h5jYEy3ALq4gyjPV1QOI=
</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: That is strange, is this a Shopware cloud shop? You might want to ask their support.